# What is the difference between an Ordinary Demand equation and an Engel curve equation?

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, supply-and-demand

I mean, an Ordinary Demand Equation measures changes in quantity of X due to changes in price Px.  Engel Curve measures changes in quantity of X due to changes in income M.  But ODE has M in it's equation, and is simply just an algebraic variant of the Engel curve!

Comment: Engel curve assumes the price is constant, and demand curve assumes income constant. There is only demand function, no engel curve equation or demand equation.

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Engel curve assumes the price is constant, and demand curve assumes income constant. There is only demand function, no engel curve equation or demand equation.